# How to get Identity Column to jump ahead (by say 1000) on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I would like to keep my pre-existing data but to cause the ID (identity) column to skip by 2000 rows.

Why is this happening? I have a scenario where I may have transactions happening on a standby server which I will need to copy to current server. I want the IDs to match. Therefore I do not want any new transactions on this server that would have the same ID as my standby server.

Hopefully this makes sense!! Thank you

Comment: For the future, this situation is why GUIDs where invented: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371762/what-exactly-is-guid-why-and-where-i-should-use-it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this by running something like

```
declare @newid int;

select @newid = IDENT_CURRENT('YourTable') + 2000;

dbcc checkident('YourTable', reseed, @newid);
```

This would reseed your table identity to be 2000 higher than it currently is and seems like it should resolve what you are looking to do.

Comment: +1; I may be preaching to the choir here, but you should get in the habit of appending a `;` to every statement in T-SQL, and you should add the schema whenever referencing an object, such as `dbo.YourTable`

Comment: @MaxVernon: Why should I get in that habit?

Comment: @Gabe For example, [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) requires semicolon usage. See also [Aaron's blog](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons).

Comment: There are other statements that need the semi colon on the previous statement too, otherwise the syntax is ambiguous. Using `WITH` to define CTEs for instance, without the semi-colon the interpreter can't tell if the `WITH` is intended to be a hint to the previous query or something to affect the next one (it could probably work it out reliably with some syntax scanning heuristic, but it doesn't and keeping your syntax unambiguous is better for human readers too).

Comment: Specifying the schema is not a huge problem until you start using more than just dbo.  Still doesn't hurt to be direct about your intention, and will prevent hard-to-troubleshoot problems in future.

Comment: Good point on the ;.  This is something I definitely need to get better about.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to remember is that an `ID` does not have to be generated by the `IDENTITY` property.

Using `IDENTITY` has challenges, since as soon as rows are moved from the standby server to the current server (using `IDENTITY_INSERT` of course) with an `ID` value higher than the current identity value it becomes the **new** current identity value. Which can complicate matters between the two servers.

For other issues see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775(v=sql.110).aspx

You might find a sequence generator with NOCACHE or some other mechanism to generate `IDs` on each machine gives you more control.  For example, you can set ID ranges that can last for a long time for each server.  For example:

- **Server1**   ID's from 1000000 to 1999999
- **Server2**   ID's from 2000000 to 2999999

Or you might suffix the numbers so that all `IDs` from **Server1** end with a 1 and all `IDs` from **Server2** end with a 2.

Or anything else that helps you avoid or limit the need for juggling values constantly or keeping the two machines aware of each other's state.